# How to make a conditional statement using two different dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets first one is all employees and who thet report to. The second dataset is all managers with non active employees.

DF1

```
 ID    Name       Status        Manager ID     Manager Name 
 101   Ashley     Active            106            Kyle
 102   Ben        Non-Active        106            Kyle 
 103   Chris      Non-Active        123            Taylor
 104   Dave       Non-Active        123            Taylor 
 105   Emily      Active            167            Paul
```

DF2

```
Manager_ID      Manager_Name       Replacing      Request Num
   106             Kyle              Ben              5678
   138             Taylor            Dave             1234
```

I want to create a new column called `Vacancy` that shows if `ID` in DF1 is Non-Active and not in DF2 then vacant.

Desired Output

```
   Manager_ID      Manager_Name        Vacancy 
      106              Kyle               0
      123              Taylor             1  
      167              Paul               0
```

I have tried:

`np.where(((df1['Status'] == 'Non-Active') &  (df2['Replacing'].isna())),1,0)`

Any suggestions? Please and thank you.

Comment: In which DF do you want to place the new columns?  Where does the column Activities come from?  Please include any code you might have tried,, we are not a tutoring service.

Comment: @itprorh66 I edited the post. but the new column should be going to DF2.

Answer (score 0):

First, we can calculate the vacancies

```
vacancies = df[df['Status'].ne('Active')] \ # Get Non-Active rows
            .groupby('Manager Name')['Name'] \ # Group by Manager Name
                                               # or Manager Id
            .agg(set) \
            - df2.groupby('Manager_Name')['Replacing'].agg(set) # Set difference
```

Which yields the names that are vacant per `Manager Name`

```
Manager Name
Kyle           {}
Taylor    {Chris}
dtype: object
```

meaning

```
>>> vacancies.str.len()

Manager Name
Kyle           0
Taylor         1
dtype: object
```

Now, we `groupby`, `pivot_table` and `assign`

```
df.groupby('Manager Name')['Status'].value_counts()\
                                    .rename('count')\
                                    .reset_index()\
                                    .pivot_table(columns='Status',
                                                 index='Manager Name', 
                                                 values='count')\
                                    .assign(Vacancy=vacancies)\
                                    .fillna(0)
```

---

```
Status        Active  Non-Active  Vacancy
Manager Name                             
Kyle             1.0         1.0      0.0
Paul             1.0         0.0      0.0
Taylor           0.0         2.0      1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
cols = ['Manager ID', 'Manager Name', 'Vacancy']

vac = (df1['Manager Name'].isin(df2['Manager_Name'])
       & df1['Status'].eq('Non-Active')).astype(int)

out = (df.assign(Vacancy=vac).sort_values('Status')
         .drop_duplicates('Manager ID')[cols].sort_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Manager ID Manager Name  Vacancy
0         106         Kyle        0
2         123       Taylor        1
4         167         Paul        0
```